# Center align content inside an affix div in bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to create a permanent, fixed sidebar using bootstrap (3). It currently looks like this:

[image]

The code for it is:

```
<div class="main container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-2 sidebar">
                    <div class="affix">
                        <p class="name-header">FIRST LAST</p>
                        <hr>
                        <nav>
                            <ul>
                                <li>About</li>
                                <li>Projects</li>
                                <li>Interests</li>
                                <li>Photography</li>
                                <li>Contact</li>
                            </ul>
                        </nav>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-1 main-content-wrapper">
                    <div class="content">
                        <div class="about section">
                            <h3>About</h3>
                            ...
```

I want to center align the text "FIRST LAST" to the sidebar, however it's center aligning to the affix div instead. How can I make the affix div span the entire width of the sidebar (col-lg-2), or rather how can I center align the text to the sidebar rather than to the affix div?

Comment: add .text-center class

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1:**

Increase the col-value in `<div class="col-lg-12 sidebar">` and give "`text-align:center;`" to the class.

**Solution 2:**

You can add the `"col-lg-offset-1"`( offset value may change based on your requirement ) class to push the column. Or you can add the following class along with the slidebar.

```
sidebar {
    height:200px;
    border: 5px solid black;
    display:block;
    margin: auto;
    width: 300px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please make the affix div "position" and make it relative,
or assign the margin or padding to it.

Answer (score 0):

Add `text-center` class to your p tag containing `FIRST LAST` text would do

```css
.sidebar {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-2">
  <div class="affix sidebar">
    <p class="name-header text-center">FIRST LAST</p>
    <hr>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li>About</li>
        <li>Projects</li>
        <li>Interests</li>
        <li>Photography</li>
        <li>Contact</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>

</div>
<div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-1 main-content-wrapper">
&nbsp;
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: The sidebar isn't 2 cols wide though

Answer (score 0):

use this code:

```
.affix{
margin: 0 auto;
text-align:center;
width:100%
}
```